# Are Spiking Neural Networks The Next Big Thing?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, sparse, artificial-intelligence

Intel recently announced their Loihi chip as part of their "Neuromorphic Computing" research, which is optimized for spiking neural networks (SNNs). I found an example of a problem in which they compared an SNN on Loihi to an ANN on a GPU, and Loihi achieved similar speed and accuracy but used less than a hundredth of the energy. I know pruned neural networks have received some interest in the last 5 or so years, and it seems deep learning is moving towards more sparse networks. I'm wondering now, should we start learning more about SNNs now that they've become more viable in recent years? And does anyone have any experience with hardware for implementing SNNs to enable the efficiency improvements. I don't believe Loihi itself will become commercially available for this purpose. I mostly use PyTorch and a GPU at home, but I wanted to know if and how I should transition to SNNs for more efficient applications of neural networks, particularly for mobile devices.

Comment: X algorithm on {hardware designed for X} is hardly comparable with Y algorithm on {hardware designed to do almost any sort of parallelizable computation}

Comment: @shimao You don’t say? But that has absolutely nothing to do with my question.

Comment: @shimao An SNN on Loihi for object detection vs an ANN on something else (like a 2070 super) for object detection IS in fact comparable. E.g. mAP, inference time, training time, size in MB, etc. What is it that you can’t compare?

Comment: a 2070 is a commodity gpu which can efficiently do almost any sort of parallel computation. it would be a fair comparison if you could render and play video games off a loihi as well